# Setting Timer Interrupt 1Hz, 2Hz... and doing all jobs in its means a kind of primitive RTOS?

Tags: c, stm32, rtos

As an example, if I need a job that need to occur 0.5 second periodically I can put in 2Hz jobs or I need 3 second, I can increase a counter 3 times in 1 Hz job etc. Could we named this a kind of basic RTOS?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your problem and your question?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, but it is not a RTOS. A RTOS has some manner of scheduler, usually with priorities, that can context switch and use different stacks for different processes.

Comment: I wouldn't even consider that to be a scheduler, let alone an RTOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling that and RTOS is a bit of a stretch, it may (or may not) be a *real-time application*, but the two are not synonymous; real-time may not need an RTOS and a system with an RTOS need not be real-time - poor application design can easily defeat that.

If the timer events are processed in the interrupt context, then that is a "*foreground/background system*", if rather you are polling/counting timer events and performing processing at designated times, then that is probably best described as a "*big-loop executive*" (and will be even less deterministic).  It may be a *framework* or a *design pattern*, but not an RTOS.

Consider this: If your timer is due to trigger at time T+1.0 and and some asynchronous event that will be processed at that time occurs somewhere between T+0.0 to T+1.0, it takes between 0.0 and 1.0 to process the event - is that real-time?  In some cases perhaps so, but not if the event must be processed in less than 1.0 time period.

In many cases that kind of timing uncertainty is unacceptable, for a UI button press it would be annoying, for an emergency stop, it could kill someone!  A typical RTOS enables deterministic response to events in the order of microseconds (regardless of tick resolution), if your timing can be as relaxed and 1 second, you may not need an RTOS.  Your system will require timer frequency to match the real-time needs of your most time-critical task - that makes it impractical for a wide range of real-time tasks.